# How to conditionally parse JSON based on settings in a Reader environment?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Is there any way to pass down a reader environment to the JSON (de)serialisation functions of Aeson? Here's a real-life example of why this could be required?

```
-- JSON instances for decimal -- ORPHAN instances

defaultPrecision :: Word8
defaultPrecision = fromInteger 2

instance ToJSON Data.Decimal.Decimal  where
  toJSON d = toJSON $ show d

instance FromJSON Data.Decimal.Decimal  where
  -- TODO: New problem! How do we get the precision dynamically, based on
  -- the currency settings of the logged-in user
  parseJSON (Number n) = return $ Data.Decimal.realFracToDecimal defaultPrecision n
  parseJSON x = fail $ "Expectig a number in the JSON to parse to a Decimal. Received " ++ (show x)
```

Comment: `instance FromJSON (Reader Decimal)` or better: `newtype DecimalWithPrec = D (Reader Precision Decimal); instance FromJSON DecimalWithPrec`. This still would not allow you to make parsing choices based on the environment, but that isn't needed for your example.

Comment: @user2407038 Sounds like that should be an answer :)

Comment: @user2407038 I tried going with your approach and got to the following - https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/6b2eaa437be9a2fff14540e0dcbbc334 - but how do I write the `ToJSON` instance?

Comment: You either pick a default argument for the reader (probably `defaultPrecision`), or you don't have such an instance. I don't know what `Decimal` type you are talking about here, but if the need for a precision argument is due to the fact that the 'decimal' in question is not (might not be) representable exactly as a finite sequence of digits, then you should see why you can't reliably serialize such a number, without arbitrarily picking a precision (you should probably elaborate where you got your `Decimal` and what the intended semantics of the instances are).

Comment: The `Decimal` type in question is from the `Data.Decimal` package. The precision for parsing will be provided by the user, which will be stored in the DB. Hence the need for a Reader environment.

Comment: Can you confirm how you want to use `parseJSON`? Is it to be able to call something like `decode "4" :: Data.Decimal.Decimal`, but use a precision found at runtime?

Comment: @MichalCharemza essentially, yes. The overall context is larger, but it boils down to this particular building block, i.e. being able to call `decode "4" :: Data.Decimal.Decimal` and use a precision that is known at the time `decode` is being called, i.e. runtime.

Answer (score 5):

If instance depends on some runtime value then what you really want is an ability to create instances at runtime. You can implement `FromJSON` for `Reader` as it's done in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/saurabhnanda/6b2eaa437be9a2fff14540e0dcbbc334). But as you correctly noticed, you can't do the same for `ToJSON` because you don't know this precision. The easiest solution would be just store precision as separate field in data type. Like this:

```
data DecimalWithPrecision = MkDWP
    { value     :: Decimal
    , precision :: Word8
    }
```

If you store this data type in your data base and query it after user login, then this is the easiest solution and doesn't require type level tricks from you.

If you don't know precision in advance, for example user inputs precision through console (I don't know why, but lets assume this), then this wouldn't work for you. As we all know that «type classes are just syntax sugar for data types», you can replace `ToJSON/FromJSON` constraints with `JsonDict` for `Money_` in the following manner:

```
newtype Money_ = Money_ (Reader Word8 Decimal)

data JsonDict a = JsonDict
    { jdToJSON    :: a -> Value
    , jdParseJSON :: Value -> Parser a
    }

mkJsonDict :: Word8  -- precision
           -> JsonDict Money_
```

You can create such dictionary (or something similar to it) on-the-fly using `Word8` from context and just pass it to function which needs it. See [this blog post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html) by [Gabriel Gonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026598/gabriel-gonzalez) for details.

If you really want to have `toJSON` implementation inside instance, you can use [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library. Precision is a natural number which gives you ability to use this library. Using it you basically can create instances in runtime as in previous approach, but you still have your type classes. See [this blog post](http://newartisans.com/2017/02/a-case-of-reflection/) where similar technique was applied to make `Arbitrary` instances depend on runtime values. In your case this will look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import           Control.Monad.Reader (Reader, ask)

import           Data.Aeson           (FromJSON (..), Result (..), ToJSON (..),
                                       Value, fromJSON, withNumber)
import           Data.Aeson.Types     (Parser)
import           Data.Decimal         (Decimal, realFracToDecimal)
import           Data.Proxy           (Proxy (..))
import           Data.Reflection      (Reifies (reflect), reify)
import           Data.Word8           (Word8)

newtype PreciseDecimal s = PD Decimal

instance Reifies s Int => FromJSON (PreciseDecimal s) where
    parseJSON = withNumber "a number" $ \n -> do
      let precision = fromIntegral $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
      pure $ PD $ realFracToDecimal precision n

instance Reifies s Int => ToJSON (PreciseDecimal s) where
    toJSON (PD decimal) =
        let precision = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
            ratDec    = realToFrac decimal :: Double
        in toJSON ratDec -- use precision if needed

makeMoney :: Decimal -> Reader Word8 (Value, Decimal)
makeMoney value = do
    precision <- fromIntegral <$> ask
    let jsoned = reify precision $ \(Proxy :: Proxy s) ->
                     toJSON (PD value :: PreciseDecimal s)
    let parsed = reify precision $ \(Proxy :: Proxy s) ->
                     let Success (PD res :: PreciseDecimal s)
                           = fromJSON jsoned in res
    pure (jsoned, parsed)
```

And then you can run it like this to test:

```
ghci> runReader (makeMoney 3.12345) 2
(Number 3.12345,3.12)
```

Comment: Would the method using reflection work with `decode` from `Data.Aeson`?

Comment: You should mention the original Functonal Pearl: Implicit Configurations http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf

Comment: @MichalCharemza I think no... Because `decode` isn't a type class method.

Comment: @phadej I mentioned `reflection` library which contains link to this paper.